# Symfony debugger is still enabled even on production

Tags: php, symfony, environment-variables

I'm every confused of this behaviour.
I Set my env to production and the debugger is still available on prod enviorment.

My .env file is like so

```
APP_ENV=production
```

And here is my Bundles Config.

```
    <?php

$bundles = [
    Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Twig\Extra\TwigExtraBundle\TwigExtraBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    EightPoints\Bundle\GuzzleBundle\EightPointsGuzzleBundle::class => ['all' => true],
];

if ('dev' === $_SERVER['APP_ENV']) {

    $devBundles = [
        Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],
        Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\MakerBundle::class => ['dev' => true],
        Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true]
    ];

    return array_merge($bundles, $devBundles);
}

return $bundles;
```

Does anyone know why my Debug is still working on prod ?

For example:

http://localhost/asd/

Returns the Symfony output error..

> ResourceNotFoundException  NotFoundHttpException
> HTTP 404 Not Found
> No route found for "GET /asd/"

Any help is apreciated.

Edit: I'm not sure if this helps but this is what i found.

If i set me `APP_EVN` to `dev`

My WebProfilerBundle is Loading, if I set it to `production` back it does not load.

Comment: Do you have a `.env.local` file on the server?

Comment: No, I don't have that on the server.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Could there be any other configuration that sets `APP_ENV`?

Comment: There is nothing else that set's the APP_ENV, which is why i'm confused.  I only have that on .env file.

Comment: Did you tried `APP_ENV=prod`?

Comment: Omg why is this the solution ? Would have never thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default production environment is called `prod`. So you have to change it to:

```
APP_ENV=prod
```